# Average and case in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, average

I'd like to have the average of a column when its bigger than zero.

```
Select Avg(Case when Column > 0 then Column else 0 end) as Avg
```

but I'm afraid the `else` clause is not correct. I want to ignore the zero values in the average.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `else` part from `case statement` so the values less than `1` will be `NULL`.

`Null` values will be eliminated by the `Avg aggregate`. So you will get the average of values which are greater then `0`. Try this.

```
Select Avg(Case when [Column]>0 then [Column] end) as [Avg]
```

### **DEMO**

Without `else` part in `case statement` (Expected Average)

```
SELECT Avg(CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN a END) [Avg]
FROM   (SELECT 2 a UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT -1) bb
```

Result : `2`

With `else` part in `case statement`.

```
SELECT Avg(CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN a ELSE 0 END) [Avg]
FROM   (SELECT 2 a UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT -1) bb
```

Result : `1`